# how to use shift on behaviorSubject?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a class with BehaviorSubject:

```
export class WordsService {
    private words = new BehaviorSubject<WordType[]>([]);
```

It was fed with subscription:

```js
init() {
    this.databaseService.fetchWords().subscribe(
        (listaWords: WordType[]) => {
            this.words.next(listaWords);
        },
        errors => console.error('err'),
        () => console.log('suceed')
    )
}
```

And as I'm refactoring this code:

```js
private fetchWord(): void{
    this.word = this.wordService.getWords().shift();
}
```

I'm trying to get variable word to have data with .shift so it can take one element from observable at once, and when it will take all elements fetching's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to transform the results from a `WordType[]` to a single `WordType`.

You can do this by applying the [`map()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator like this:

```
init(){
  this.databaseService.fetchWords().pipe(
    map(words => words.shift())
  )
  .subscribe(
    (listaWords: WordType[]) => {
      this.words.next(listaWords);
    },
    errors => console.error('err'),
    () => console.log('suceed')
  )
}
```

However, you don't actually need a BehaviorSubject to do this, you can simply declare your observable directly from your service call:

```
public word: Observable<WordType> = this.databaseService.fetchWords().pipe(
  map(words => words.shift()),
  catchError(error => console.log(error))
);
```

Now, the `word` observable will only emit the value you are interested in.

This allows you to possibly use the `async` pipe in your template to manage the subscription and not need to do it yourself in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it without shifting.

Imagine you have any observable value, for each emition of this observable value you want to pull a word. In my example this observable value is a page click.

Then you can do something like this:

```
const clicked$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const words$ = of(['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'XX']);


const wordToPrint$ = zip(
  clicked$,
  words$.pipe(concatAll()),
).pipe(
  map(([,word]) => word),
);

wordToPrint$.subscribe(console.log);
```

See stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ep1k3v?file=index.ts